# nginx + passenger + rails - 403 forbidden error

Tags: nginx, ruby-on-rails-3, passenger, http-status-code-403

I have install Nginx server and configured all needed stuff, but currently I'm having error with 403 forbidden error. Log says:

```
2010/12/28 17:38:59 [error] 28664#0: *27 directory index of "/home/appuser/test_app" is forbidden, client: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx, server: localhost, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx"
```

My config:

```
worker_processes  1;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    passenger_root /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.2;
    passenger_ruby /usr/bin/ruby;
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    sendfile        on;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  localhost;
        root /home/appuser/test_app;
        passenger_enabled on;
    }
}
```

Any solutions?

Comment: This is a question for serverfault.com

Answer (score 14, accepted):

change

```
/home/appuser/test_app
```

to

```
/home/appuser/test_app/public
```

Answer (score 3):

The nginx root directive should point to the 'public' directory of the app.

Comment: doesn't this only affect static file serving?

Answer (score 0):

By any chance are you using rvm to install Ruby?  Judging by your paths, you aren't.  But in case you are, you need to be careful with the passenger_* configuration options.  Take a look here: [Rails 3.1, nginx, Passenger directory index forbidden](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8131806/rails-3-1-nginx-passenger-directory-index-forbidden/8142328)