# Rails 3.1, nginx, Passenger directory index forbidden

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, nginx, passenger

I'm getting the following error in nginx (with a 403) when I visit .com:

```
[error] 5384#0: *1 directory index of "/u/apps/<app-name>/current/public/" is forbidden
```

I'm on Ubuntu 10.04 and I can't for the life of me get nginx, Passenger, Rails 3.1, and Capistrano to play nicely.

I'm deploying to /u with Capistrano.  Everything in /u is 755, owned by the app user.

/u/apps//current/public/ has all my assets, the favicon, and everything else you'd expect.

When I add `autoindex on` to nginx.conf I get a listing of the public/ directory, which leads me to believe that I don't have a permission problem.

My nginx.conf file is default expect for:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name <app-name>.com;
    passenger_enabled on;
    root /u/apps/<app-name>/current/public/;
}
```

And my Capistrano deploy.rb file has nothing unusual.

Any ideas why the rails app doesn't seem to be starting?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Alright, I answered my own question.  I was missing passenger_ruby and passenger_root configurations in my nginx.conf file.  Note that the passenger_ruby path needs to be the wrapper if you're using RVM.

```
passenger_root /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/passenger-3.0.9;
passenger_ruby /usr/local/rvm/wrappers/ruby-1.9.2-p290/ruby;
```

Comment: Well, if this solved your problem, go ahead and accept your own answer.

Comment: Any idea why it has to be the wrappers ? I don't really know what are the different directories about in RVM but why not bin instead ?

Comment: This happens if Passenger can't be loaded for any reason.  If the path is wrong, you see the same result.

Answer (score 11):

If you already have `passenger_root` and `passenger_ruby` in your `nginx.conf`, but having this error, you must have some location blocks. Then you must specify
`passenger_enabled on;` inside each location block.

Comment: This dig the trick for me, I forgot to add the passenger_enabled on to the sites configuration.

Comment: Not true in my case. I have no location blocks, but I still get this error.

Comment: I had no location blocks either so I added a `location / { passenger_enabled on; }`

Answer (score 9):

In case you are running into this with Passenger 5+ and your Rails app is a 2.3.x app, you now need to add a `config.ru` file to your app:

```
# Require your environment file to bootstrap Rails
require ::File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/config/environment'

# Serve static assets from RAILS_ROOT/public directory
# use Rails::Rack::Static
# Dispatch the request
run ActionController::Dispatcher.new
```

More details in the [official announcement](https://blog.phusion.nl/2015/03/04/phusion-passenger-5-0-1-released/) and [github ticket](https://github.com/phusion/passenger/issues/1418).

I know the OP's question was about Rails 3.1 specifically but wanted to include this here since the output is identical and searches led me to this post.

Comment: Spent 3 hours looking for this! Many kudos. Thanks!!

Answer (score 4):

Sorry to answer to an old question, but it seems relevant (at least for me ;-) )
I had a similar problem and manage to solve it thanks to this post but in a different way.
Alternatively, you can setup the /etc/nginx/nginx.conf to use:

```
passenger_root /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/locations.ini;
passenger_ruby /usr/bin/ruby;
```

And then make sure the locations.ini is current by running:

```
passenger-config --make-locations-ini
```

As said, this worked for me, though I'm not an expert, maybe I'm playing with the wrong parameters.