# Rails application deployment and Nginx file permissions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linux, nginx, deployment, permissions

I've just set up my application and deployed it to `/srv/my_app_name` using Capistrano. However, when I try to access my app, I receive `403 Forbidden nginx/1.6.2` error. My Nginx runs under `www-data` user, but now I'm trying to understand what access rights should be granted to Nginx for my application folder. In my `/var/log/nginx/error.log` file I have this:

```
015/03/01 09:42:16 [error] 19451#0: *1 directory index of "/srv/my_app_name/current/public" is forbidden, client ...
```

This is the result of `ls -l` command for `/srv` folder:

```
drwxrwxr-x   3 root deploy  4096 Feb 28 16:04 srv
```

Resulf of `namei -lm /srv/my_app_name/current/public/` command:

```
# namei -lm /srv/my_app_name/current/public/
f: /srv/my_app_name/current/public/
drwxr-xr-x root   root   /
drwxrwxr-x root   deploy srv
drwxrwxr-x deploy deploy my_app_name
lrwxrwxrwx deploy deploy current -> /srv/my_app_name/releases/20150301140926
drwxr-xr-x root   root     /
drwxrwxr-x root   deploy   srv
drwxrwxr-x deploy deploy   my_app_name
drwxrwxr-x deploy deploy   releases
drwxrwxr-x deploy deploy   20150301140926
drwxrwxr-x deploy deploy public
```

My app Nginx config:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

    passenger_enabled on;
    rails_env production;
    # root /srv/my_app_name/;
    root /srv/my_app_name/current/public;

    # Make site accessible from http://localhost/
    server_name localhost staging.my_app_name.de www.staging.my_app_name.de;

    location / {
            # First attempt to serve request as file, then
            # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
            # Uncomment to enable naxsi on this location
            # include /etc/nginx/naxsi.rules
    }
}
```

My previous application was deployed to `/var/www` and worked perfectly, but I've read that it is not the best place for application used as a service, so decided to place this one in more appropriate folder, but now I'm stuck with file permissions.

Question:

1. should I add some rights for `www-data` only to public folder (`/srv/my_app_name/current/public`), or to the whole app folder (`/srv/my_app_name`)?
2. What are the proper rights? I currentcly use `deploy` user for deploy, that is added to `deploy` group.
3. How to add those rights (I mean commands, cause I'm not very good in Linux file permissions)?

Comment: Could you please provide output of `namei -lm /srv/my_app_name/shared/public` command?

Comment: + Use should use `/srv/my_app_name/current/public` instead of `/srv/my_app_name/shared/public`

Comment: Added `namei -lm` result to question.

Comment: @maxd yes, I've changed config and restarted nginx, but result is the same

Comment: I've changed `namei -lm` command for appropriate folder. Updated question.

Comment: Seems like you have all `o+r` permissions for all directories. Is it mean that your problem doesn't related to directory permissions. Look at this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8131806/rails-3-1-nginx-passenger-directory-index-forbidden). Maybe you have a problem described in this post.

Comment: Yes, this really now seems to be not related to file permissions. But I've got passenger_root and passenger_ruby in my config. I've added for testing purposes `autoindex  on;` to my config and server listed directory, so it seems to be incorrect Nginx configuration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that my nginx config was incorrect. For some reason this one worked perfectly:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    passenger_enabled on;
    passenger_app_env staging;
    root /srv/my_app_name/current/public;
    server_name localhost other_hosts;
}
```