# 403 forbidden nginx with passenger rails... don't think it's permissions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, nginx, passenger

I am trying to set up phusion passenger with nginx and rails on ubuntu 14.04. I can only get 403 Forbidden errors on the page.

I have checked the user that is running nginx to be www-data:www-data and i have given permission and ownership to www-data:www-data.

The reason i don't believe that it is a permissions issue is because it gives me the same error when i (very temporarily) had all permissions in the /var/www to 777 -R

crazy, right?

I have done this install several times before and have never run into this. passenger is version 5 now, maybe something has changed?

I have tried from using the gem
rvmsudo passenger-install-nginx-module (which builds nginx for me and puts everything in /opt)

I have also tried using phusion passengers repos and used apt-get to install nginx and passenger.

i get the same thing each time.

thanks for any tips

Comment: logs??  They should point you to why..

Comment: this is in the logs. 2015/08/13 10:39:31 [error] 5471#0: *1 directory index of "/var/www/admin_website/public/" is forbidden, client: 192.168.1.17,

Comment: Normally that happens if your `passenger_ruby` and `passenger_root` are not set correctly.  see:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8131806/rails-3-1-nginx-passenger-directory-index-forbidden

Comment: These are correct. I set them in the nginx.conf file after installing the passenger gem. During the process it displays in the terminal what these settings are. I have also verified the location myself. Thanks.

Comment: does your nginx log show that passenger is being loaded?

Comment: yes, and that is very strange because when i run passenger-status after, it says that it is not currently serving any applicaitons.

Comment: Pointing your ngnix config might help at this point..